# Difference between header() and constant("$[headers.}")

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

I have a question about the `header()` method and the expression `constant("${headers}")`.

I have a camel route that I'm testing an error flow forcing with a process, but when applying the code:

```
onException(Exception.class)
.onWhen(
header(Exchange.FAILURE_ROUTE_ID).isEqualToIgnoreCase(enrichToken)
)
```

this flow is ignored and the generic is applied, but when using:

```
onException(Exception.class)
.onWhen(
constant( Exchange.FAILURE_ROUTE_ID + " == " + enrichToken
)
```

The flow works correctly as expected.

NOTE: `enrichToken` is an attribute that carries the name of the route that suffers the forced error.

I expected both modes to return the same true.